CRC6 calculation in C
I try to calculate a CRC6 of my data from an encoder and I am not able to achieve the correct CRC.
The used CRC from the sensor has the polynom 0x43 and I tried to implement the a C function like this:
//CRC6 calculation
static uint8_t crc6(uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    uint8_t j = 0;
    uint8_t crc = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];  // Initial XOR with input data
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) {  // Process each bit of the current byte
            if (crc & 0x20)  // Check the MSB of the crc
            {
                crc = (crc << 1) ^ CRC6_POLY;  // Shift left and XOR with polynomial if the bit is set
            }
            else
            {
                crc <<= 1;  // Just shift left
            }
            crc &= 0x3F;  // Ensure crc remains 6-bit
        }
    }

    return crc;
}

I could extract some sample data, which gives the calculated CRC and the actual CRC sent back by the sensor:
(Top Dec, Bot HEX)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
The CRC are not the same and I don't know why.
Edit: The CRC data is inverted according to the datasheet, but this still did not solve the problem.
I call the CRC function like this:
uint8_t crc1 = crc6(enc1_data, 3);
uint8_t crc2 = crc6(enc2_data, 3);
uint8_t crc1_is = ~(enc1_data[3] >> 2) & 0x3F; //crc is inverted!
uint8_t crc2_is = ~(enc2_data[3] >> 2) & 0x3F; //crc is inverted!

Edit2: I added also the datasheet (Page 49 is the CRC6):
https://www.ichaus.de/product/ic-pz-series/#documents
Edit3: So far I had no success, but I got an example from the manufacturer. My start value in the SPI_CRCS is 0x00, so that should be right.

My crc calculation routine looks now like this:
//CRC6 calculation
static uint8_t crc6(uint8_t *data, uint8_t len)
{
    uint8_t i = 0;
    uint8_t j = 0;
    uint8_t crc = (0x00 << 2); //Start value in SPI_CRCS register

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];  // Initial XOR with input data
        for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)  // Process each bit of the current byte
        {
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ (0x43 << 2) : crc << 1;
        }
    }

    return crc;
}

And it is called like that:
uint8_t crc1 = crc6(enc1_data, 4); //CRC should be zero to be correct

So in the end, I should expect a crc = 0x00, but I still get random values.

I found out, that the CRC received in the data is inverted, but also when I use ~CRC, it still does not match.

Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?  Added unit tests to verify the logic is right?

Yes, the logic is as stated above. I don't know if my implementation of the CRC6 calculation is wrong, if the CRC6 is wrongly extracted out of the encoder data (since it is inverted and shifted because of also a warning and error bit) or if the CRC is calculation is limited to 3 or 4 bytes (all position data or also last byte with CRC)

Test your function against some known working CRC calculator first (there are many of these online).

The CRC6 includes the two bits that are in the same byte with the CRC - your current code is not taking those into account.  You need to pass all four bytes to the CRC algorithm, and check for a specific value at the end - https://crc-reveng.septs.app/ derives the following parameters for your sample data: width=6  poly=0x03  init=0x24  refin=false  refout=false  xorout=0x00  check=0x26  residue=0x00

You need to know the starting value of the CRC, which is set in register SPI_CRCS.

You need to calculate the CRC in the high six bits of the register, not the low six bits. You also need the initial value, which can be found in the SPI_CRCS register. It might change, so you should read it if possible. For your examples, the initial CRC is 0x24, which is shifted up by two bits for the initial register value.
static uint8_t crc6(uint8_t const *data, size_t len) {
    uint8_t crc = (uint8_t)(0x24 << 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ (3 << 2) : crc << 1;
    }
    return crc;
}

That will return the CRC shifted up by two bits, which matches what is in your CRC/ERR/WRN column. The low two bits of that value in the message would need to be zeroed, e.g. msg[3] & 0xfc, before comparing that with the computed CRC, since the ERR and WRN bits might not be zero, even though they are in your examples.
Example with your data:
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t crc6(uint8_t const *data, size_t len) {
    uint8_t crc = (uint8_t)(0x24 << 2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ (3 << 2) : crc << 1;
    }
    return crc;
}

uint8_t msg[][4] = {
    {0x90, 0x90, 0x3d, 0xc0},
    {0x90, 0x90, 0x41, 0xc8},
    {0x90, 0x90, 0x45, 0xf8},
    {0x9f, 0x2c, 0x25, 0xa0},
    {0x9f, 0x2c, 0x29, 0xf0},
    {0x9f, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0xc0},
    {0xc2, 0x6c, 0x81, 0xb0},
    {0xc2, 0x6c, 0x75, 0xf0},
    {0xc2, 0x6c, 0x85, 0x80}
};

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t const n = sizeof(msg) / sizeof(msg[0]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%02x, %02x\n",
               crc6(msg[i], 3) ^ msg[i][3], crc6(msg[i], 4));
    return 0;
}


Hi, i still got no right CRC with your code and at the moment I don't see why. I got a CRC example from the manufacturer, but that still did not really help me. The start value is 0x00 and the polynomial 0x43

@HansLüthi My code computes the values in the fourth column of your provided table, using the starting value 0x24 and the first three columns of your table. If you're not getting that, then you need to put your code in your question, so that we can see what you're doing wrong.

@HansLüthi If you have new information from the manufacturer, then add that to your question.
